# Flutter TextFormField Validation Error Text Padding

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-textformfield

I have a TextFormField. This widget validation is empty show error text. However, the error text fill looks like the picture. How can i solve it.

[image]

```
 SizedBox(
            height: 50,
            child: TextFormField(
              validator: (val) {
                if (val!.isEmpty) {
                  return "Boş Geçilemez";
                }
                if (val.length > 100) {
                  return "Karakter Sınırı Hatası";
                }
                return null;
              },
              obscureText: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                 
                  suffixIcon: const Icon(
                    Icons.lock_outline_rounded,
                    color: Color(0xffBDBDBD),
                  ),
                  hintText: AppLocalizations.getString("sifre"),
                  contentPadding:
                      const EdgeInsets.only(top: 14, left: 10, bottom: 10)),
              controller: passwordController,
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Please add your current codes

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you want to center align the hint text in TextFormField, then do not assign manual height to TextFormField just remove Container or SizedBox over TextFormField.

Comment: If you want to make your error text start from just below the TextFormField, then you have to manually manage the Error texts below TextFormField.

Comment: @Ahmadhassan Should I use a snackbar for the error message or should I display it in a different area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you use same content padding for top and bottom, and try increasing the height of TextFiled like 64.

And use `autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,`

```dart
SizedBox(
  height: 64,
  child: TextFormField(
    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
    validator: (val) {
      if (val != null && val.isEmpty) {
        return "Boş Geçilemez";
      }
      if (val!.length > 10) {
        return "Karakter Sınırı Hatası";
      }
      return null;
    },
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        suffixIcon: const Icon(
          Icons.lock_outline_rounded,
          color: Color(0xffBDBDBD),
        ),
        hintText: "sifre",
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
          top: 14,
          left: 10,
          bottom: 14,
        )),
  ),
),
```

Comment: This is OK. But shouldn't there be a different solution for the error text?

Comment: Oh sorry,  Are you trying to get rid of 1st error focus? It will be easy if you can provide full Form

Comment: @HüseyinBedir yes, just remove contentPadding from TextFormFiled but it will remove padding from hint text too